# Set Button height to 100% of parent element without setting parent height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a div that contains a button, a table and another button in that order, I want the buttons to be to the left and right of the table and have the same height as the table. The buttons are supposed to be back and forward buttons to change the data in the table.

I have gotten close to what I want using `float: none` on the div and `float: left` on all items, which aligns them correctly but when I try `height: 100%` on the buttons they expand on the entire window which is not what I want.

In quirks mode I can achieve something similar with

```css
div {
    height: 50%;
}
    
button {
    height: 100%;
}
    
table {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

which worked in testing on accident because my screen size matched so it displayed like I wanted it to, this changed however as soon as I resized the window or added `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Is there any way to accomplish this without using `display: flex`?

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Under construction</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body>

<div>
    <button>&larr;</button>

    <table style="border: none">
    <thead><th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th></thead>
         <tbody>
             <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
             <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
             <tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
         </tbody>
    </table>

    <button>&rarr;</button>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```css
td {
    background: green;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: share your HTML code

Comment: @TemaniAfif it's just <div><button></button><table></table><button></button></div> nothing else

Comment: it cannot only be that code, you have for sure data inside your table .. we need a *real* code to provide accurate solution, I can provide you a solution with that code but maybe it won't work in your case

Comment: and why you cannot use flexbox? this is the trivial solution here

Comment: @TemaniAfif there is no content yet, just placeholders at the moment, it will be filled dynamically by a php-sql backend later which is just plain text, I have added my current code to the question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif because I need legacy browser support. Unfortunately this is not up to me :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position:absolute` seems to be the *only* solution here:

```css
td {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 7px;
}
.box  {
  border:1px solid red;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:0 50px; /* 50px is considered to be the width of button so adjust it based on your case*/ 
}
.box button {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
}
.box button:last-of-type {
  left:auto;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <button>&larr;</button>

  <table style="border: none">
    <thead>
      <th>a</th>
      <th>b</th>
      <th>c</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>G</td>
        <td>H</td>
        <td>I</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <button>&rarr;</button>
</div>
```

Or you can consider another table structure but you will need to adjust the HTML code:

```css
.box table td {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
.box,
.box > tbody,
.box > tbody > tr > td{
  height:100%;
}

.box button {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="box">
  <tr>
    <td><button>&larr;</button></td>

    <td>
      <table style="border: none">
        <thead>
          <th>a</th>
          <th>b</th>
          <th>c</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>A</td>
            <td>B</td>
            <td>C</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>D</td>
            <td>E</td>
            <td>F</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>G</td>
            <td>H</td>
            <td>I</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </td>
    <td><button>&rarr;</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Although this looks like a lot of code for what seems like a simple task, I can't find any other solution. I'll use this for now but deep down I refuse to believe that this is the only way.

Comment: @TheSupremeGod there is other ways but will involve either Flexbox or CSS grid or another table but you need to adjust the html (check the update)